# Eigenvalues of time lagged covariance matrix - should be always real and positive?

Tags: covariance, eigenvalues

Consider two random variables $X_t$ and $X_{t+\tau}$; where both come from random variable $X$ but are lagged by $\tau$. Assume that both are mean-free. If we want calculate covariance matrix of them, then we do:

$$\Sigma = X_t^T X_{t+\tau}$$
if we perform eigendecomposition

$$A\Sigma = \Sigma\Lambda$$

Then if the time lagged covariance is properly converged, all the eigenvalues are going to be positive, non-complex ?

Comment: What do you mean by "properly converged"?

Comment: @mhdadk
There's enough samples to calculate it, so that it does not change much if we add more samples

Comment: One could check for diagonal dominance, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87528/a-practical-way-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite. By intuition, if autocorrelation $<X_{t}, X_{t+\tau}>$ is much higher than the rest, it is probable that $\Sigma$ is positive definite.